# MS Access: Method 'open' of object '_Recordset' failed

Tags: ms-access

The code I am using:

```
Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset

rs.Open "select * from QueryName", CurrentProject.Connection, adOpenDynamic, adLockReadOnly
```

Why in the blazes is this returning an open error? The query itself is totally fine.

The query, btw:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Zone.Office, ledger.representative
FROM ledger LEFT JOIN [Zone] ON ledger.branch = Zone.app_office
WHERE (((Zone.Office)<>"" And (Zone.Office) Is Not Null) AND ((ledger.representative)<>"" And (ledger.representative) Is Not Null))

UNION SELECT DISTINCT Zone.Office, ClientList.representative
FROM ClientList LEFT JOIN [Zone] ON ClientList.branch = Zone.app_office
WHERE (((Zone.Office)<>"" And (Zone.Office) Is Not Null) AND ((ClientList.representative)<>"" And (ClientList.representative) Is Not Null))

UNION SELECT DISTINCT Zone.Office, ghs.representative
FROM ghs LEFT JOIN [Zone] ON ghs.branch = Zone.app_office
WHERE (((Zone.Office)<>"" And (Zone.Office) Is Not Null) AND ((ghs.representative)<>"" And (ghs.representative) Is Not Null))

UNION SELECT DISTINCT Zone.Office, Prospects.representative
FROM Prospects LEFT JOIN [Zone] ON Prospects.branch = Zone.app_office
WHERE (((Zone.Office)<>"" And (Zone.Office) Is Not Null) AND ((Prospects.representative)<>"" And (Prospects.representative) Is Not Null))
```

Comment: When you say the query is fine, does it use reserved words? Not everything that runs in the query design window will run in ado ( http://support.microsoft.com/kb/238243 ). As an aside, why ado and not native dao?

Comment: I don't understand ado vs. native dao? How would I use native dao in this case? And I don't know what you mean by "reserved words" unless you mean something like "distinct"?

Comment: Your question is short on information. Where are you running the code that you cannot use DAO (Dim rs As DAO.Recordset)? A reserved word might be "SELECT User FROM ATable" User is a reserved word. There are lists, eg http://support.microsoft.com/kb/286335

Comment: Hm I am not using any reserved words like that anywhere

Comment: How might I use DAO here? rs.open doesn't work when I switch it to dao.recordset

Comment: Where are you running your code? In MS Access?

Comment: Yes. I am currently opening the recordset and then using a loop to iterate through each record to run an exporting process, moving via rs.movenext.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need a reference to `Microsoft DAO x.x Object Library` or in 2010 (or 2007?) and on `Microsoft Office x.x Access Database Engine Object Library`

```
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset

Set rs = CurrentDB.OpenRecordset("NameOfquery")
```

Comment: This worked. I wonder why DAO worked here but not ADODB? Strange! Thanks.

Comment: I would say it is because you do not have a query that is valid in ADO.